Do moderators have the ability to add/remove badges from user accounts?
Do moderators have the ability to add badges (in the case of bugs, edge cases, etc.) or remove badges (in the case of vote abuse, etc.)?

Even staff and developers can't add badges manually just like that, except for very specific badges e.g. Not a Robot.

Why would you think that they can? Have you seen any such behaviour, or indications of such? I just wonder why you asked this question.

@Greenonline A while ago I didn't get the Beta badge for a site I participated in and met the rules for, so I was wondering whether the issue could be resolved in that way.

No. This includes cases where users earn badges for activity that is later removed (such as votes being invalidated); once a badge is awarded, it's almost never then later removed (and moderators do not have the ability to do so).

I suppose they could remove tag badges in theory by deleting all the tagged answers or retagging the questions.
